# Problems while transforming pandas dataframe to PySpark RDD?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

With pandas `read_csv()` function I read an `iso-8859-1` file as follows:

```
df = pd.read_csv('path/file', \
                   sep = '|',names =['A','B'], encoding='iso-8859-1')
```

Then, I would like to use MLLib's word2vect. However, it only accepts as a parameter RDDs. So I tried to transform the pandas dataframe to an RDD as follows:

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
spDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df['A'])
spDF.show()
```

Anyhow, I got the following exception:

```
TypeError: Can not infer schema for type: <type 'unicode'>
```

I went to [Pyspark's documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=createdataframe#pyspark.sql.SQLContext.createDataFrame) in order to see if there is something like an encoding parameter, but I did not found anything. Any idea of how to transform an specific pandas dataframe column to a Pyspark RDD?.

**update:**

From @zeros answer this is what I tried save the columnn as a dataframe, like this:

```
new_dataframe = df_3.loc[:,'A']
new_dataframe.head()
```

Then:

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
spDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(new_dataframe)
spDF.show()
```

And I got the same exception:

```
TypeError: Can not infer schema for type: <type 'unicode'>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `df['A']` is not a `pandas.DataFrame` but `pandas.Series` hence when you pass it to `SqlContext.createDataFrame` it is treated as any other `Iterable` and PySpark doesn't support conversion of simple types to `DataFrame`.

If you want to keep data as Pandas `DataFrame` use `loc` method:

```
df.loc[:,'A']
```

Answer (score 0):

From @zeros323 answer I noted that it actually was not a pandas dataframe. I [consulted pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) and found that `to_frame()` can convert that specific column in a pandas dataframe. So I did the following:

```
new_dataframe = df['A'].to_frame()
new_dataframe.head()
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
spDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(new_dataframe)
spDF.show()
```